# moveit tutorial

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it's hard to follow up moveit1 documentation can anyone suggest to me some other sources for moveit1 melodic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380722/moveit-tutorial/) by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-06-21**:
You can try Youtube videos if the tutorials are insufficient, but working through the tutorials and suggesting improvements may be more beneficial for you and the community.

**Comment by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on 2021-06-21**:
can you suggest some youtube videos because I cant find any

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-06-21**:
No, but googling "moveit tutorial video" turns up a 2-hour video called "MoveIt training for beginners", so I don't think they're hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, install moveit on your computer

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ros-noetic-moveit
```

Then you need to have a `.urdf.xacro` file for the manipulator you are trying to setup. This is the most important part, so make sure you have the correct file.

You can launch the assistant with

```
 roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
```

These are the tabs that you need to setup for the most basic setup:

1. Start: Create New MoveIt Configuration Package
2. Load your robot URDF file
3. Self-Collisions: Generate Collision Matrix
4. Virtual Joint: Create a virtual joint between your robot's base link and the world frame
5. Planning Groups: select KDLKinematicsPlugin and add the necessary joints to the group
6. Robot Poses: add desired robot poses that Moveit will have
7. ROS Control: setup Joint Trajectory Controller
8. Finally, generate the package in your workspace.

You can then test your MoveIt setup by launching the file

```
roslaunch [your_moveit_config_pkg] demo.launch
```

If you need a video describing these steps, you can watch this video that takes you through the process above:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdzmMRXAks4&ab_channel=TheConstruct

---

Originally posted by [rodrigo55](https://answers.ros.org/users/53015/rodrigo55/) with karma: 156 on 2021-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently "Google for 'moveit tutorial video'" was a sufficient answer.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-06-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1